# Angular - port number used to send a form

Tags: angular, api

I have created a form in app which has a login button, when i click on the login button i get an error in developer tools which say

POST https://localhost:7259/Passenger net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I know I am listening on port 44453, where is the app getting the port 7259 from?

i have changed the port in launchSettings.json but no luck

Comment: I'd try to search through your code editor for the port in your project. Do you have a proxy.conf.json set up? If that's not the case than delete cache and restart your app.

Comment: yes, there is a proxy.conf.json file

Comment: If you didn't add it, delete it.

Comment: i have deleted the file which was created when i started the project but now i am getting an unhandled exception saying the file does not exist, where is visual studio looking to get this error?

Comment: i have deleted the proxy.conf.js from angular.json but still have the same error what i started with POST https://localhost:7259/Passenger net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: just noticed on the localhost:7259 in my launchSettings.json file it wants connect to 44453 when i launch the app and type 7259 in the localhost the error is this site cannot be reached in the browser

Comment: where is angular getting the localhost:7259 from? angular is listening on port44453